# rvalue reference binding to an lvalue for std::function types

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

Why there is no compilation error at `(@)` in below code? I thought `lamb` is an lvalue so it will not get bound to an rvalue reference.

```
using FunctionType = std::function<void()>;
using IntType = int;
struct Foo {
    void bar(FunctionType&&) {}
    void baz(IntType&&) {}
};

Foo foo;
foo.bar([]() {}); //OK
auto lamb = []() {};
foo.bar(lamb); //(@) No compilation error?!
foo.baz(5); //OK
int i = 5;
foo.baz(i); //Error
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since `lamb` is a lambda and not a `std::function`, a temporary `std::function` has to be created and passed to `bar()`.  The temporary binds to the rvalue reference.

Your code is equivalent to this:

```
auto lamb = [](){};
foo.bar(FunctionType(lamb));
```

You would get a compile error if you did this instead:

```
FunctionType func = [](){};
foo.bar(func);
```